# unique nonnegative square root of diagonal matrix J

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let nonnegative diagonal matrix $D = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}\lambda_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \lambda_n\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Prove that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\sqrt{\lambda_1} & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \sqrt{\lambda_n}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is the unique nonnegative square root of $D$. Here, nonnegative is defined as self-adjoint ($A = \bar{A}^\intercal$) with positive eigenvalues.

This has come up as a smaller part of a larger proof, and seems intuitively obvious but I can’t find a straightforward proof. Seems hard to account for the fact the square root of $D$ can be non-diagonal (but won’t be nonnegative as a result). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar exercise myself and this is how i solved it

$\textbf{Proposition}.$ Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be symmetric $\geq 0$; there is a unique $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, symmetric $\geq 0$, s.t. $B^2=A$.

$\textbf{Proof}.$ -proof of details is your business-

$i)$ There is $P\in O_n$ s.t. $A=Pdiag(\lambda_1I_{i_1},\cdots,\lambda_kI_{i_k})P^T$, where the $(\lambda_i)$ are $\geq 0$, distinct and $i_1+\cdots +i_k=n$.

$ii)$ Since $B$ is a square root of $A$, $AB=BA$ and $B=Pdiag(U_1,\cdots,U_k)P^T$, where ${U_j}^2=\lambda_jI_{i_j}$.

$iii)$ Since $B$ is symm. $\geq 0$, $U_j$ is symm. and has a sole eigenvalue $\sqrt{\lambda_j}\geq 0$. Then $U_j=\sqrt{\lambda_j}I_{i_j}$. $\square$